# Как лучше сделать фоновое изображение?

Tags: html, css

Как лучше сделать фоновое изображение из макета? Объединить слои и сохранить, как png или есть способ правильнее? Плюс ведь качество картинки может упасть

Макет https://www.figma.com/file/zwa7oxqCS43WTsPEAQhMik/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0?node-id=1%3A6

Comment: Картинка отдельно, фон отдельно (в векторе), конвертнуть картинку в webp для браузеров поддерживающих формат.

Comment: разместить друг за другом с помощью z-index?

Comment: фон из png переделать в svg?

Comment: Почему именно webp? Качество не пострадает?

Comment: при конвертации сами выставляете качество сжатия, желательно сжимать с исходника а не со сжатого уже jpg, тогда получится файл в раз 5 меньше чем jpg и качество лучше